# SharePoint LDAP filtering of People Picker users

Tags: sharepoint, filtering, stsadm

On my WSS server I have run the following stsadm command to filter the people picker results:

stsadm.exe -o setproperty -url http://myserver -pn "peoplepicker-searchadcu
stomfilter" -pv "(memberOf=CN=SharePoint,OU=AccessGroups,DC=contosio,DC=local)"

My WSS sites are all used by different groups of users.

Whenever I create a new site collection in WSS I want to ensure that I can filter the people picker to only show he relevant users for that group - can I automate this or would I have to manually do something like the above stsadm command?

All the best

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a SPWebProvisioningProvider this is a piece of code which can be run when a new site (based on a specific site definition) is created.

You would need to ensure that your site collection root was using the appropriate site definition.

[More info can be found here.](http://blogs.technet.com/apurdon/archive/2008/02/05/the-mystery-that-is-spwebprovisioningprovider.aspx)

You would need to either implement your stsadm call using the object model, or else wrap the specific call to that command in some custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [peoplepicker-**searchadcustomfilter**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263452.aspx) applies to the entire web application, even if I specify a site collection in the URL parameter.

```
stsadm –o setproperty –propertyname peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -propertyvalue "(|(userPrincipalName=*mycompany.com)(memberof=CN=client_users,OU=client_Users,OU=Extranet,DC=client,DC=int))" -url http://myserver/sites/site1 

stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -url http://myserver/sites/site1
stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -url http://myserver/sites/site2
```

When I ran the above, I expected to see site1 with the custom LDAP query, and site2 with no filter applied.  But instead I see the custom LDAP query on all site collections in this web application.  Bummer.

Looks like Microsoft needs to clarify the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263452.aspx).